# Simple python + igraph usage

Tags: python, igraph

I am using python + igraph 0.6 for the first time and have some basic questions.

First, I would like to make a random graph and then insert a clique into it somewhere.

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(50,0.1)
h = Graph.Full(5)
```

How do I make a new graph g2 with h connected by two edges to the graph g?

Second, having done this I would like to find maximal cliques and show in a picture where they are.  Call the combined graph g2.

```
mcliques = g2.maximal_cliques(4, 7)
```

How can I now plot the cliques we have just found either separately or in the graph g2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer to your first question:

```
g2 = g + h
g2.add_edges([(0, 50), (1, 51)])
```

or even simpler:

```
g2 = g + h + [(0, 50), (1, 51)]
```

Here we make use of the fact that the `+` operator between two graphs creates a disjoint union of the two graphs, and since `igraph` always uses a consecutive vertex ID range, we can simply know that vertices 0-49 of `g2` will span `g` and vertices 50-54 will span `h`.

Regarding your second question, you did not specify what exactly you mean by plotting the cliques, but a possible solution is as follows:

```
group_markers = [(clique, "gray") for clique in mcliques]
plot(g2, mark_groups=group_markers)
```

See the documentation of `Graph.__plot__` for more information about the `mark_groups` parameter; basically it is either a dictionary mapping colors to groups of vertices (vertex ids), or a list yielding pairs of vertex ids and colors. The vertex groups are then enclosed by a shaded area with the given color as background.

Comment: Thanks!  I look forward to being fully fluent in the usage of igraph as it seems very powerful.

Comment: The simplicity of the igraph is great!